# Magento 2: Calling Restful Web service GET and POST

Tags: magento2, module, cron, rest-api, web-services

Any one knows how to call restful web service from Magento 2?

Please guide me with a format how it can be done.

Any links to guide me with examples of POST or GET etc.

I want to Call below URL in Magento, Please suggest me structure of module

> http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo

This URL results with following Data:

```
{
status: {
message: "the daily limit of 30000 credits for demo has been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use the demo account for your application.",
value: 18,
    }
}
```

Do I have to create a module? if not where I need to Call this URL?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: check it https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/rest_front.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom module and use curl in your controller action to call this URL and Fetch response body

**Curl Example (Sharing the required fragments of the file)**

```
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;
class Curlex extends AbstractHelper {
        /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl
        */
        protected $_curl;

      public function __construct(Curl $curl) 
        {

            $this->_curl =$curl;
        }
         /**
         * Send SMS
         * @param type $mobile_no
         * @param type $body
         */
        public function getResponse($url)
        {
          $url = urlencode($url);  
          $this->_curl->get($url);
          $response = $this->_curl->getBody();

         return $response
        }

}
```

the above example is for GET you can use for similar way ([Guide for Curl with post data](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58#post-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded))

Comment: I have followed your example, but it says page is not found. can u check this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227634/magento2-restful-web-service-calls-controller-is-not-showing)

Answer (score 1):

Here we have 2 action item here.

1. You are using "demo" username to call the webservice which is already crossed the maximum limit. Either you need to subscribe for that webserice ( as a paid serice ) or get another sample username which you can use it.
2. To call the webservice, you can create custom module in magento 2 and integrate the same.

app/code/Devi/CustomService/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Devi_CustomService',
    __DIR__
);
```

app/code/Devi/CustomService/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Devi_CustomService" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/Devi/CustomService/etc/frontend/routes.xml

app/code/Devi/CustomService/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

namespace Devi\CustomService\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    Curl $curl
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->curl = $curl;
}


/**
* Get order details ( order status, total, items, total invoiced )
* return Json Param
**/
public function getCitiesDetails()
{
    $uri = 'http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=9.9&east=22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo';
    $result = $this->curl->get($uri);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);

}
}
```

app/code/Devi/CustomService/Controller/Search/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Devi\CustomService\Controller\Search;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
/** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */
protected $resultPageFactory;

/*** @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context      */
public function __construct(
    Context $context, 
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Devi\CustomService\Helper\Data $data
)
{
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->helper = $data;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * Get City Details.
 *
 * @return JSON City details
 */
public function execute()
{
    // Call Helper function to get order details //
    $this->helper->getCitiesDetails();
    die;
}
}
```

I hope, It will be helpful.