# Magento2 : Restful Web service Calls - controller is not showing

Tags: magento2, module, web-services

I have followed [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226214/magento2-calling-restful-web-service-get-and-post) Question to write the web-service call. but controller is not showing it says 404 Not Found.

```
<?php

namespace Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Service extends AbstractHelper {
        /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl
        */
        protected $_curl;

        public function __construct(Curl $curl) 
        {

            $this->_curl =$curl;
        }
         /**
         * Send SMS
         * @param type $mobile_no
         * @param type $body
         */
        public function getResponse($url)
        {
          $url = urlencode($url);  
          $this->_curl->get($url);
          $response = $this->_curl->getBody();

         return $response;
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            echo "Welcome to Service Call";
        }

}
```

> \app\code\Autosynch\synchProduct\etc\frontend\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="Autosynch" frontName="auto">
            <module name="Autosynch_synchProduct" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

after trying below answer i am getting below error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Strict Notice: Declaration of Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service::getResponse() should be compatible with Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction::getResponse() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\app\code\Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service.php on line 40

Exception #0 (Exception): Strict Notice: Declaration of Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service::getResponse() should be compatible with Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction::getResponse() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\app\code\Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service.php on line 40
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(444): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2048, 'Declaration of ...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 40, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(444): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#3 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Autosynch\\synch...')
#4 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Autosynch\\synch...')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\App\Router\ActionList.php(91): is_subclass_of('Autosynch\\synch...', '\\Magento\\Framew...')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\App\Router\Base.php(295): Magento\Framework\App\Router\ActionList->get('Autosynch_synch...', NULL, 'page', 'service')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\App\Router\Base.php(161): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->matchAction(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(50): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->match(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\module-store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\index.php(41): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#27 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
<?php
namespace Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;

class Service  extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
        /**
        * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
        * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
        */
        protected $_curl;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            Curl $curl
        ) 
        {

            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->_curl =$curl;
        }
         /**
         * Send SMS
         * @param type $mobile_no
         * @param type $body
         */
        public function getMyCurlResponse($url)
        {
          $url = urlencode($url);  
          $this->_curl->get($url);
          $response = $this->_curl->getBody();

         return $response;
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            echo "Welcome to Service Call";
        }

}
```

You should extend this class `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`.

Comment: it looks same after adding this also. i will check again after Setup:upgrade

Comment: have you added route in routes.xml?

Comment: Yes, Please check the question updated

Comment: I have updated my answer, you are getting that error because we have used same `method` `getResponse` which Magento using in `vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/AbstractAction.php`.