# Magento2 external api integration

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am currently working on a project which I need to call an external Api which has a bearer token. The Api endpoint comprises product information like SKU and Name which I need to save on Magento. Below is my code but it's not still working.
Can someone please help me out with my code, maybe I'm missing something?

```
<?php

namespace Dynamics\Integration\Model;

use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;

class Product
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl
 */

protected $curlClient;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory
 */
private $productInterfaceFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
 */
private $productRepository;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory $productInterfaceFactory
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
 * @param Curl $curl
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory $productInterfaceFactory,
                            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface   $productRepository,
                            \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl               $curl
)
{
    $this->productInterfaceFactory = $productInterfaceFactory;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->curlClient = $curl;
}

public function getAllProducts()

{
    $uri = "myUri"
    $this->curlClient->addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer Mytoken in here");
    $this->curlClient->addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    $this->curlClient->get($uri);
    $body = $this->curlClient->getBody();
    $httpCode = $this->curlClient->getStatus();
    $response = \Zend_Json::decode($body);


        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $newData */
        $newData = $this->productInterfaceFactory->create();
        foreach ($response as $item) {
            $newData->setSku($item->value->ItemModelGroup);
            $newData->setId($item->value->ItemNumber);
            $newData->setName($item->value->SearchName);
            $this->productRepository->save($newData);
        }

}

}
```

Comment: Hey, sorry, but I am not really sure what do You need to do, Can You please explain it a bit better? Also  some specific cases may be helpfull

Comment: Thanks @KonradSiamro i have and api endpoint that comprises some of the product information. how can i call /integrate this with my magento products

Comment: Hey, sorry but it is still a little bit small info. Is the Endpoint external endpoint or magento endpoint? Do You want to call it from magento? Or do You want to make it works as magento endpoint and call Magento Endpoint to make it works? Does it comprise Magento products or external products? Or Do You have to write the whole Endpoint in Magento? Just take Your time and explain what You need. Otherwise noone will be able to help you :)

Comment: @KonradSiamro The endpoint is an external endpoint from Dynamics365 and it comprises external product information. i want to call this endpoint on magento2

Comment: You can try it https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/create-integration-with-api.html or You can use curl https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226214/magento-2-calling-restful-web-service-get-and-post  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861986/how-to-call-an-external-api-in-magento-2-2

Comment: @KonradSiamro Thanks for taking me through but still not working. I have updated my question and see what have done so far, i don't know if i'm missing something. kindly help me out

Comment: But whats mean, iit doesnt working? Is any error thrown? Or No connection is established? Or Data are wrong? How can we help You if we dont even know how the response from the Endpoint looks like?

Comment: Eventually You can use xdebug, to go line-by-line and check whats going on and why.